# How to skip preview window when refactoring through Shift+F6

Tags: refactoring, pycharm

I am working with PyCharm 3.0.1.
When trying to refactor literals with Shift+F6 and pressing Refactor button
i am forwarded to preview window where i have to click Refactor button with a
mouse to actually apply refactoring.

[image]

Is there any way to skip this preview window and get rid of using mouse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't skip it as far as I recall, but you *can* not use a mouse. When the pop-up screen comes up, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (underline under R), and then <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (underline under D).